# Qual a diferença entre "===" e "==" em Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Eu gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre == e === na hora de fazer expressões e condicionais com elixir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diferente da maioria das linguagens, `===` não faz uma dupla verificação de equivalência e tipo. Tal como ocorre em javascript:

```
> 1 === "1"
false
> 1 == "1"
true
```

Em Elixir, a diferença entre `==` e `===` é que o último é mais rigoroso ao comparar números inteiros e flutuadores:

```
iex> 1 == 1.0
true
iex> 1 === 1.0
false
```

Você pode usar `==` em todas as condições que não utilizam `numbers` tendo em vista que a difença entre `===` e `==` afeta a comparação apenas entre números. 
 Vou deixar duas fontes aqui para maior compreensão do assunto:

> Documentação:
>   https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-operators.html 
>   Pergunta no stackoverflow em Inglês:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32347090/difference-between-double-equals-and-triple-equals-for-string-comparision-in-eli